# Ionic app in iOS unable to play local audio with cordova-plugin-media

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I can't play an audio in ionic with cordova-plugin-media, but that only happens in iOS and with a local audio.

Controller is quite simple, just set a `new Media` and play it. Callbacks just return a log of theirs parameters.

```
$scope.data = {};
$scope.playMedia = function(){
    // Get file path base for every each platform 
    var pathBase = ionic.Platform.platform().toLowerCase() === "android" ? "/android_asset/www/" : "";
    var source = pathBase + "audios/parts/99.mp3";
    console.log("source: " + source);

    // Set source and callbacks
    $scope.data.media = new Media(source, mediaSuccess, mediaError, mediaStatus);
    $scope.data.media.play();

    // Update media position every half second
    $interval(updatePosition, 500);
};

function updatePosition(){
    $scope.data.media.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        if (position > -1) {
            $scope.data.position = position;
            console.log(position);
        }
    });
};
```

Media status return 2, [which means](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media#constants) `Media.MEDIA_RUNNING`, so file exists and was found but as you see position is 0.

```
2016-03-04 17:58:21.358 Play Local Audio[2549:1228498] source: audios/parts/99.mp3
2016-03-04 17:58:21.374 Play Local Audio[2549:1228498] THREAD WARNING: ['Media'] took '14.875000' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2016-03-04 17:58:21.376 Play Local Audio[2549:1228657] Found resource '/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/E70EE8B6-F5A8-49F7-9A7D-3A963C3AD439/Play Local Audio.app/www/audios/parts/99.mp3' in the web folder.
2016-03-04 17:58:21.395 Play Local Audio[2549:1228657] Playing audio sample 'audios/parts/99.mp3'
2016-03-04 17:58:21.398 Play Local Audio[2549:1228657] Playing stream with AVPlayer & custom rate
2016-03-04 17:58:21.400 Play Local Audio[2549:1228498] mediaStatus:
2016-03-04 17:58:21.401 Play Local Audio[2549:1228498] 2
2016-03-04 17:58:21.401 Play Local Audio[2549:1228498] $scope.data.media:
2016-03-04 17:58:21.401 Play Local Audio[2549:1228498] {"id":"a15cc81b-fd6d-4e12-7e95-0361d0a977a1","src":"audios/parts/99.mp3","_duration":0,"_position":-1}
2016-03-04 17:58:21.866 Play Local Audio[2549:1228498] 0
2016-03-04 17:58:22.341 Play Local Audio[2549:1228498] 0
2016-03-04 17:58:22.842 Play Local Audio[2549:1228498] 0
2016-03-04 17:58:23.343 Play Local Audio[2549:1228498] 0
2016-03-04 17:58:23.845 Play Local Audio[2549:1228498] 0
2016-03-04 17:58:24.346 Play Local Audio[2549:1228498] 0
2016-03-04 17:58:24.847 Play Local Audio[2549:1228498] 0
2016-03-04 17:58:25.348 Play Local Audio[2549:1228498] 0
2016-03-04 17:58:25.850 Play Local Audio[2549:1228498] 0
2016-03-04 17:58:26.351 Play Local Audio[2549:1228498] 0
```

But if I try with and external audio: `http://www.sample-videos.com/audio/mp3/crowd-cheering.mp3` it works. This is the audio that I am using to play locally.

```
    $scope.data.media = new Media('http://www.sample-videos.com/audio/mp3/crowd-cheering.mp3', mediaSuccess, mediaError, mediaStatus);
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug of the plugin that affects iOS 9.2, I changed two lines as described [on the pull request](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media/pull/85) and audio is played.

File `src/ios/CDVSound.m`, replace

Line 219:

```
 CDVAudioFile* audioFile = [self audioFileForResource:resourcePath withId:mediaId doValidation:YES forRecording:NO];
```

Line 226:

```
NSURL* resourceUrl = audioFile.resourceURL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello there is another way / workAround to overcome this issue as posted in this article here :

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ios-9-2-cordova-plugin-media-no-sound-fix-on-the-way/45100/1

In the Method :

```
- (void)startPlayingAudio:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
```

replace these lines :

From:

```
 if (audioFile.rate != nil){
    float customRate = [audioFile.rate floatValue];
    NSLog(@"Playing stream with AVPlayer & custom rate");
    [avPlayersetRate:customRate];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Playing stream with AVPlayer & custom rate");
    [avPlayer play];
}
```

To:

```
if (audioFile.rate != nil){
    float customRate = [audioFile.rate floatValue];
    NSLog(@"Playing stream with AVPlayer & custom rate");
    [audioFile.player setRate:customRate];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Playing stream with AVPlayer & custom rate");
    [audioFile.player play];
}
```

Again credit goes to the writer of the answer at this link :

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ios-9-2-cordova-plugin-media-no-sound-fix-on-the-way/45100/1